# 3 models in laravel 4 - select with relation whereHas Query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relationship

I have 3 models:

- User
- Planet
- Sunsystem

Relations:

In the User Model:

```
    public function planets() {
        return $this->hasMany('Planet');
    }
```

In the Planet Model:

```
    public function sunsystem() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Sunsystem');
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
```

And in the sunsystem Model:

```
    public function planets() {
        return $this->hasMany('Planet');
    }
```

Now I want select all the sunsystems with all the related planets
but only the sunsystems where the related planets belongs to the actual user (in this example ID 12).
But how did I get the correct result?
This is what I try, but it gives me only ONE sunsystem, but I expect 2 sunsystem. I think my query is wrong...:

```
        $s = Sunsystem::whereHas('Planets', function($q) {
            $q->whereHas('User', function ($u) {
                $u->whereUserId(12);
            });
        })->get();
```

This also doesn't work:

```
     $s = Sunsystem::select('Sunsystems.*')
       ->join('planets','planets.sunsystem_id','=','sunsystems.id')
       ->join('users','users.id','=','planets.user_id')
       ->where('users.id','=',12)
       ->get();
```

If there are 2 planets with different sunsystem_id but the same user_id I get only one sunsystem, but I expect two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try it

```
$s = Sunsystem::select('Sunsystems.*')
     ->join('planets','planets.sunsystem_id','=','Sunsystems.id')
     ->join('users','users.id','=','planets.user_id')
     ->where('users.id','=',12)
     ->get();
```

Comment: nope.. does'nt work. If there are 2 planets with different sunsystem_id but the same user_id I get only one sunsystem, but I expect two.